# Draw smooth transparent line

Tags: android, canvas, line, draw

I am trying to draw smooth line following my finger. The problem is in superposition. Left example is array of drawLine, and right is drawPath. Is it way to make it like smooth left example?

[image]

Comment: did you try using the ANTI_ALIAS flag on the Paint youre using to draw?

Answer (score 0):

Construct the line as a solid color, then wrap that line inside of a drawable. Turn this drawable transparent, and then draw it to the screen.